# Samsung TV connected to PC for Powerpoint

Tags: tv, vga

I have a 42" Samsung LCD TV connected to a Dell computer with a PCI Radion 9000 via a 35' VGA cable. It's purpose is to run power point presentations over the TV for our retail store. I have tried every combination of button clicking on the video card options, and everything on the TV, and I still get black bars on the top and bottom of the image. It looks like I am watching a old wide screen movie on a full screen TV. The TV's suggested resolution is 1024x768, and that is what the output is set to. I have tried this with a nVida PCI card as well with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the settings of the display adapter, there is a setting that says hide video modes that my monitor cannot support. Once I unchecked that, I was able to fine tune the resolution to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Samsung's settings? In particular, the "P.Size" setting. It will have about 4 different options, and the one you probably want is "Full".

Comment: 2 options 16:9 and 4:3. both still have the black bars. 4:3 just adds additional gray bars to the left and right.